# PHP Error Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays

I have class `Router` which has array of routes property

```
<?php
class Router
{
    private $routes = [];

    function setRoutes(array $routes)
    {
        $this->$routes = $routes;
    }
}    
?>
```

In other File routes.php :

```
<?php    
$routes = [
    'users' => 'users.php',
    'comments' => 'comments.php'
];    
?>
```

And I use it like :

```
<?php    
require __DIR__ .'/Data.php';
require __DIR__ .'/Router.php';
require __DIR__ .'/../routes.php';

$router = new Router;
$router->setRoutes($routes);
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];    
?>
```

But I'm getting

Notice: Array to string conversion in `/../XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TestPro/core/Router.php`

Why this error is occurring ?

Comment: Is there any more code in the file that contains the `Router` class? Can you give us the content of the line of code within `Router.php` that creates the notice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YOu should replace this line:

```
$this->$routes = $routes;
```

By:

```
$this->routes = $routes;
```

[Attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) should be called without `$`

Answer (score 1):

You problem is the use of private variable in the class, you need change the class for:

```
class Router {

    private $routes = array();

    function setRoutes(array $routes){
```

> $this->routes = $routes;

```
    }

}
```